# What is text service, how to interact text service framework in Windows 8?

Tags: keyboard, windows-8, ime

I am developing third party IME in metro application (C#) ,I need to understand that how to text service interact to Text Service Framework (TSF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Text Services Framework is available from a C++ component in a Metro style app.  Here is a [list of the available COM APIs from C++ in a Metro style app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452772.aspx).  Scroll down to Text Services Framework and you will see that most APIs are available.

In terms of how to do it, it depends on what you want to do -- you call COM components in the normal way that you would from any other C++ app.  Here is a reference that should help on [various usages to TSF APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).